# react native flatlist change orientation

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have flatlist with enabled horizontal option like page, it work well when is portrait or landscape load. When mode are changed width and height are mess up. I try to calculate width and height in addEventListener. Is there some better solution. Can re render flatlist without losing state and props. This is getItemLayoutPot where define layout.

```
getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
    {length: this.state.width, offset: this.state.width * index, index}
)

 <FlatList
    onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged }
   viewabilityConfig={{
                      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
                    }}
                    ref={ref =>  this.flatListRef = ref }
                    data={dataar}
                    horizontal={true}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    extraData={this.state} 
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    removeClippedSubviews={false}
                    initialNumToRender={20}
                    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
                    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
                    initialScrollIndex={this.state.numPage}
                    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
                    pagingEnabled={true} ....
```